# Getting Communities Url from PageReference

Tags: community, pagereference

I have a VisualForce page that I would like to open in a new tab via Javascript.

javascript (in VF page, called onClick)

```
function myFunction(){
   OpenInNewTab("{!url}");
}
```

Apex controller

```
public String getUrl(){
    return Page.MyPage.getUrl();
}
```

The URL that gets generated is the standard SF url `/apex/mypage`, but for the communities user it needs to be `myCommunity/mypage`.

Is there anyway to get the correct Url **WITHOUT** hardcoding the communities prefix in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled across the same issue a couple of days ago. This is how I resolved it...

In my case it was a button (could be a link as well), I've added onclick javascript event to call a javascript function:

```
<input type="button" value="Proceed" onclick="redirectToMyPageJS();" />
```

Then I wrote my JS function which gets the community name from the URL:

```
<script>
    function redirectToMyPageJS()
    {
        // It's always the 3rd element in the list which is the community name when accessed from the communities site
        redirectToMyPage(window.location.href.split('/')[3]);
    }
</script>
```

and calls my action function passing the community name as a parameter:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!redirectToMyPage}" name="redirectToMyPage" >
    <apex:param value="" name="portalName" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Then finally in my APEX method I have:

```
public pageReference redirectToMyPage()
{
    return new PageReference('/' + Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('portalName') + '/MyOtherPage');
}
```

Comment: bit more hacking than I would like but at there no hardcoding of the portal name

Comment: I assume there would be an idea on ideaexchange but this is an absolute must feature for Apex. For now we have to live with this hack :)